# What is these two address returned from println of empty interface variable in go?

Tags: go, pointers, memory, interface

Studying interface in GoLang, I found this example code I couldn't understand.

```
package main

func main() {
    var a interface{} = 1

    i := a
    j := a.(int)

    println(i)
    println(&i)
    println(j)
}
```

The result is

```
(0x459d00,0x4765a8)
0xc000034760
1

Program exited.
```

Can you teach me what is the tuple of addresses?

Is there a good resources which I can learn of the memory layout of Go language?

Comment: https://research.swtch.com/interfaces

Comment: "Can you teach me what is the tuple of addresses?" This is an implementation detail every compiler (and even every compiler version) may print something different here. You cannot learn anything sensible from this type of experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [link](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) provided by [kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix)

I found this resource which depicts the structure of interface object.
[image: interface structure]

As we can see in the implementation code of runtime print function.
[go/src/runtime/print.go#L260](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8e34d779578736942c78f9857f5bb9b9025815c6/src/runtime/print.go#L260)

```
func printiface(i iface) {
    print("(", i.tab, ",", i.data, ")")
}
```

The first address is pointer of itable and the second is pointer of data.

You can learn further information on the [link](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) provided by [kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix)